# Reading .btr file using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, btrieve

I need to import data from a .btr file (text.btr) to Access database using VB.net. I searched in google but didn't find any solution for this.

Any help would be highly appriciated.

Thanks, Yogi

Comment: You ought to be able to find that answer at http://btr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](http://ww1.pervasive.com/developerzone/platforms/net.asp) is what you need.  It's a free download from Pervasive, the makers of Btrieve (which is what I'm assuming your .btr files are)